# InnoDB/phpmyadmin problem

Tags: php, sql, mysql, phpmyadmin, innodb

I recently reinstalled phpmyadmin and Apache and am trying to restore my databases.
Some are InnoDB.

I tried copying the .frm files from a backup; the databases did appear but the tables from the old ones did not show at all.

Anyone know how to fix this? I've never had this problem before, and I'm struggling to find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

InnoDB also stores data in it's own data directory, not just in the .frm files. Unless you've backed up that as well, your data is lost.

Next time use mysqldump.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you also reinstalled MySQL, as simply reinstalling Apache or phpmyadmin would not result in a loss of data.

If this is not the case, you should state exactly how you set up phpmyadmin, and exactly how you are looking for your old databases/tables.

## Assuming you also reinstalled MySQL

As Maerlyn noted, mysqldump is always the best option.  Always get a full backup with mysqldump if you are upgrading MySQL.

If your new install of MySQL is a more recent version than the last one, you will probably need to use the [mysql_upgrade](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-upgrade.html) utility to bring your table files up to speed.